# How to prove a relation on a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am looking to show that a relation of a set if reflexive. How do I go about formally writing that out, and how do I show logically that it is reflexive?

Suppose $R$ is a transitive and symmetric relation on a set $A$ and that
$∃a ∈ A$ such that $aRx$ for all $x ∈ A$. Prove that $R$ is reflexive.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint : If $aRx$ then $xRa$ (symmetry), and if $xRa$ and $aRx$ then  $xRx$ (transitivity).

Comment: What is the definition of symmetry?  How can you use the definition to prove that since $aRx$ for all $x\in A$, then $xRa$ for all $x \in A$.  Similarly, using the definition of transitivity, Since there exists $a\in A$ such that $\forall x\in A,$ $aRx,$ and $xRa$ means  .... (use transitive property to conclude what you are trying to conclude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in A$. Then there exists a $x \in A$ with $aRx$. Because of the symmetry we also have $xRa$. Since $R$ is transitive it follows from $aRx$ and $xRa$ that $aRa$. Hence $R$ is reflexive. I hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

So, let $x \in A$. We wish to show that $xRx$. By our third hypothesis, $aRx$. Since __________ $xRa$, and then since $xRa$ and $aRx$, by _________________, we have that $xRx$.

Filling in the blanks will provide a complete proof.